# Use Partitioned Topics with AMQP 1.0 and JMS 1.1 on Azure

Tags: java, azure, jms, amqp, azureservicebus

Two Azure documents indicate ability to use partitioned topics.

However there are no examples of using JMS with partitions from Java code.

Is it actually feasible/supported to do this?

[servicebus with amqp](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-partitioned-queues-and-topics-amqp-overview/)

[jms with partitions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-jms-api-amqp/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the sections [`Create partitioned topics`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-partitioned-queues-and-topics-amqp-overview/#use-amqp-with-partitioned-topics) & [`Create a Topic`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/#create-a-topic), you can create a partitioned topic via adding the code below or using [REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt639409.aspx) with Resource Management.

```
ServiceBusContract service = ServiceBusService.create(config);
TopicInfo topicInfo = new TopicInfo("TestTopic");
// Enable partitioning for topic
topicInfo.setPartitioningPolicy(PartitioningPolicy.MESSAGE_PARTITIONING);
```

More details, please see the javadocs for the classes [`TopicInfo`](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/servicebus/models/TopicInfo.html#setPartitioningPolicy-com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.servicebus.implementation.PartitioningPolicy-) & [`PartitionPolicy`](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/servicebus/implementation/PartitioningPolicy.html).

For messaging using JMS with partitions for Topics, you can try to refer to the article [`How to use Service Bus topics and subscriptions`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-java-how-to-use-topics-subscriptions/#send-messages-to-a-topic) to write the java code with partition key using the classes [`BrokeredMessage`](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/services/servicebus/models/BrokeredMessage.html), please see the code below.

```
BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage("MyMessage");
message.setPartitionKey("<partitionKey>");
service.sendTopicMessage("TestTopic", message);
```

Hope it helps.